# How could I do import * form dynamically loaded modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I able to load a module in python using

```
mod = importlib.load_module('module_name')
```

Now I want to load everything from mod
using this way

```
from mod import *
```

How could I do that?
Above statement gives me error saying, no module name mod.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I have multiple settings file and I want to load only one setting file based on some string input. the basic application uses everything loaded from setting file.